# Retrieve an object by variable containing object name

Tags: mongodb

I've got an document in MongoDB which looks like this:

```
[
  {
    _id: 1234..,
    obj1: { name: "A" },
    obj2: { name: "AB" },
    obj3: { name: "ABC" },
    obj4: { name: "ABCD" },
  },
  {
    _id: 5678..,
    obj1: { name: "B" },
    obj2: { name: "BC" },
    obj3: { name: "BCD" },
    obj4: { name: "BCDE" },
  }
]
```

and so on. I've got an API that I query for this with an URL with a querystring with the named object. the URL could potentially look like this `http://api.domain.com?size=obj2`

Now I would like to query my mongodb and returning only the objects that match with the `req.query.size` variable, all my other `.find()` that I've ever wrote do have something that I could reference to but here all I got is the object name.

Is this doable or am I forced to inject something like this into all my documents `obj2: { name: "AB", objectName: "obj2" }` just to be able to do `.find({ objectName: req.query.size })`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guess that structure like this will be better

```
{
    'obj2' : { name: "AB", objectName: "obj2" },
    'obj3' : { name: "ABC", objectName: "obj3" },
    'obj4' : { name: "ABCD", objectName: "obj4" }
}
```

**Reasons**

1. You can not create index on document key value so in the future you may have problem with this
2. You can not make query by document key value, only by values that stored on key
3. With structure like you have you will have problems with perfomance

Comment: This is what I eventually did. I realised that it was a lot simpler to just query my db with `Model.find({}, req.query.size)` and according to others and now also you, it would give me performance problem.